# Much GridViews together in a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, gridview, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I developing an Android App to solve the "Rubiks Cube". First the Cube will be scanned from each side of the Cube. After color recognition a new activity starts and show the result in a 2D-model. This is realized in much GridViews. For each side i have one GridView.

Now my problem: I've set each Gridview clickable but only three of them are clickable.
The Grids wich works are the first with the white facelet in the middle, the Grid with the blue facelet in the middle and the Grid with the yellow facelet in the middle. All the other Grids are not clickable, but why? I need it to implement the OnItemClickListeners for each GridView so if necessary to correct a color.

My XML File looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


     <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/gridviewU"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:numColumns="auto_fit"
     android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
     android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
     android:columnWidth="28dp"
     android:gravity="center"
     />

     <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/gridviewF"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:numColumns="auto_fit"
     android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
     android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
     android:columnWidth="28dp"
     android:focusable="true"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_below="@id/gridviewU"
     />

     <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/gridviewD"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:numColumns="auto_fit"
     android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
     android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
     android:columnWidth="28dp"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_below="@id/gridviewF"
     />

     <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/gridviewB"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:numColumns="auto_fit"
     android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
     android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
     android:columnWidth="28dp"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_below="@id/gridviewU"
     /> 

     <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/gridviewL"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:numColumns="auto_fit"
     android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
     android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
     android:columnWidth="28dp"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_below="@id/gridviewU"
     /> 

    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridviewR"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
    android:columnWidth="28dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_below="@id/gridviewU"
    />     
</RelativeLayout>
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks...

[EDIT]
I've solved my problem. Now i use an AbsoluteLayout with fix coordinates for each GridView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved. See the EDIT-line above.